# query with two table result mapping

Tags: c#, activerecord, nhibernate, hql

I created a hql query, which has a result with two tables. Now I want to map my result in an iterable list.

```
        string hql = "select distinct l, b from Lieferung as l " +
                     "inner join l.Bestellung as b";
        var hbq = new HqlBasedQuery(typeof(Lieferung), @hql);
        hbq.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToEntityMap);
        var result = ActiveRecordMediator.ExecuteQuery(hbq);
```

Now I want to iterate through my result with a foreach loop. But it doesn't work. I don't now how I can map my result in something like:

```
        IList<Tuple<Lieferung, Bestellung> result
        //or
        IList<Result> result
        public class Result //or struct
        {
            Lieferung Lieferung;
            Bestellung Bestellung;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
List<Lieferung> list = new List<Lieferung>(results.Count);
for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
{
    list.Add((Lieferung)results[i]);
}
```

Comment: The result was a ArrayList with a HashTable. After a few tries it works. You have to map the result first and than you can loop through it.

Comment: Thanks for the notes. Was glad to show you the right direction.